# Configuring ADFS for ASP.Net Core 2.0 , Angular 4 application

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, oauth, visual-studio-2017, adfs

I am really stuck at situation and unable to find correct solution for my scenario.

I have created an ASP.Net Core application with built in template for Anuglar 4
Which provides ready made configuration for running application and extended features and customized it as per my development process.
I am stuck at situation where I need to configure ADFS authentication in the application
1) I have tried implementing WS-Federation refering Microsoft documentation which seems not suitable due to Angular
2) I am trying to implement OAUTH in Angular component configuring httpauthtokenhandeler and generating bearer token but ended up here too as 
I am not able to reach to component code due to configuration that need to configure.

Currently I have added index.html page at directory level where app-root is called but it never goes to component to generate token and call adfs url

Could you please suggest clean / neat approach for implementing ADFS authentication technique for the the given approach, I have not found end to end tutorial for implementing this, most importantly this is on premise configuration and not azure or some cloud ..
Help greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are some samples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/ad-fs-development).

The SPA one seems the most appropriate.

With Angular, WS-Fed is a bad choice. OpenID Connect / OAuth is the way to go (as per the samples).

Comment: Thank you for your response, the SPA example seems to be more related to AngularJS , but will try to explore how OpenID or OAuth used for Angular 4 and ASP.Net Core as that seems to be option. thank you again.